# Extract specific arch and version of apk from play store

Tags: download, x86, android-x86

I would like to download an apk from the playstore. I own the app, and am enrolled in the beta program for it. The problem is, I need an x86 beta version of the app. Searching around is hard, given majority of devices are arm64 based. I discovered [gplaycli](https://github.com/matlink/gplaycli), but it doesn't give me the option to pick the arch I want. Any ideas?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser. Unfortunately, your question is outside of the scope of SuperUser as this is not about computers, but about phones. I'm sure android.stackexchange.com is better suited for this. That said, keep in mind that x86 and x64 are a completely different architecture than arm. I'm not even sure it is possible what you're asking.

Comment: @LPChip Ah right I forgot about that site. Anyways, someone made downloading the arm64 version possible, odds are it's possible to tweak it a bit to allow downloading the x86 version. Looking to see if anyone knows a tool that does allow me to download x86 beta versions of an apk from the store.